# How to set camera preview size for the samsung tab E

Tags: android, android-camera

I have developed app to take picture and upload it in cloud .App is working fine for all the mobile device .App got crashed in Samsung Galaxy Tab E and i got the error like

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1940)
    at CameraActivity.surfaceChanged(CameraActivity.java:401)
```

Please help me to do this and here is my code, to set camera preview sizes

```
List<Camera.Size> sizes = camParams.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
camParams.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
camera.setParameters(camParams);
camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
camera.startPreview();
```